# obtener texto interno de option seleccionado creado previamente por javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando n cantidad de inputs Nota credito, basicamente es un div que contiene un input readonly llamado Nota credito, abajo un select con clase "n_credito" y otro input con clase "monto". 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando un funcion on change para ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on('change','.n_credito', function () {
    //console.log($(this));
    var ncredit = $('select.n_credito option:selected').text();
    //console.log(ncredit_valor);
    //var ncredit_cor = ncredit_valor.split('e: ');
    //var ncredit = ncredit_cor['1'];
    console.log(ncredit);
    $(this).closest('div').find('.monto').val(ncredit);
    $(this).closest('div').find('.monto').attr("min","0");
    $(this).closest('div').find('.monto').attr("max",ncredit);
    ncredit = 0;
});
```

Basicamente mete el texto del valor seleccionado en el campo monto. Sucede que cuando solo existe un uno creado asigna el valor perfectamente. Cuando hay mas de uno parece que concatena los textos de los nota de credito creados.
En la funcion on change meto el valor seleccionado en la variable n_credit. Cuando hay dos o mas campos como en la imagen y le doy al select activando la funcion onchange guarda lo siguiente en n_credit

400-- Seleccione nota de credito --

Comment: Creo que tu problema se simplificaría mucho si agregas identificadores a los elementos, que se usen en los métodos. Eso agrega un poco de código al crearlos pero simplifica los scripts de manejo.

Comment: Disculpa, no llevo mucho en Js ¿A que te refieres con identificadores? Lo busque pero no entiendo bien como aplicarlo en este caso.

Comment: Todo elemento HTML tiene un identificador entre sus atributos: <etiqueta id="identificador" otros_atributos >; contenido <;/etiqueta> ó <etiqueta id="identificador" otros_atributos value="valor" />; Si no lo estableces el navegador establece uno por defecto. Conviene establecerlo explícitamente para facilitar el acceso y manejo desde los scripts.